# View DWG on Mac OS

Tags: viewer, dwg

Is there any way to view DWG files (created in AutoCAD) on a Mac ?

Comment: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-for-mac-general/dwg-viewer-for-mac/td-p/4300645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SolidWorks eDrawings Viewer](http://www.solidworks.com/sw/products/free-cad-software-downloads.htm) opens DWG files along with SolidWorks files for viewing.